# Using Advanced custom fields Repeater field in WooCommerce custom product Tab

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

I am using a Repeater of Advanced custom fields for the content of the my additional custom WooCommerce Tab. The repeater is inside a group field.

I manage to display the custom fields that is outside the repeater field.

Here is the code I used in my `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'dl_custom_product_designer_tab' );
function dl_custom_product_designer_tab( $tabs ) {
    // ensure ACF is available
    if ( !function_exists( 'have_rows' ) )
        return;

    if ( get_field('designer') ) {
        $tabs[] = array(
            'title' => 'DESIGNER',
            'priority' => 50,
            'callback' => 'dl_custom_designer_tab'
        );
    }
    return $tabs;
}

function dl_custom_designer_tab() {
    $designer = get_field('designer');
        echo '<p>'.$designer['designer_image'].'</p>';
        echo '<p>'.$designer['designer_name'].'</p>';
        echo '<p>'.$designer['designer_short_description'].'</p>';
        // loop through the rows of data
        $achievements = get_field('designer_achievements');
        if( $achievements ) {
            // loop through the rows of data
            echo '<ul>';
            foreach($achievements as $achievement){
                // display a sub field value
                echo '<li>'.$achievement['achievement'].'</li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
}
```

Now the problem is the field inside my repeater field: The repeater sub field is not displaying anything.

What I am doing wrong? How can I have the output for the repeater sub fields?

---

Edit: [A screenshot of the ACF settings repeater field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83SVo.png).

Comment: the repeater field return you an array so if you have only one row in the repeater field its should be `$designer[0]['designer_image']` and so on... if you have more you should use a loop...

Comment: @JohnAshleyNohay I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> **UPDATE** *(new functional alternative)*:
>
> Apparently this doesn't works with "product" post type…** This looks like a bug in this plugin *(I have been able to test the same case and to reproduce the issue)*.
>
> **It should be reported to the authors support treads**… I have do it on my side.

---

**A temporary solution *(as long as this bug is not solved by ACF team)***

This is is custom function replacement for ACF repeater dedicated functions:

```
/**
 * Custom function: Get an array of ACF repeater sub-field.
 *
 * @param string $master_field (the
 * @param string $repeater_field
 * @param array $sub_fields
 * @output formatted html
 */

function repeater_subfield( $group_name, $repeater, $subfield ){
    global $post, $product;

    $repeater_meta_key = $group_name.'_'.$repeater;
    $rows = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $repeater_meta_key, true );
    for($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++){
        $subfield_meta_key = $repeater_meta_key.'_'.$i.'_'.$subfield;
        $output[] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $subfield_meta_key, true );
    }
    if( count($rows) > 0 ) return $output;
    else return;
}
```

Then your tested and functional code should be:

```
// Add a custom product tab
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'dl_custom_product_designer_tab' );
function dl_custom_product_designer_tab( $tabs ) {
    // ensure ACF is available
    if ( !function_exists( 'have_rows' ) )
        return;

    if ( get_field('designer') ) {
        $tabs[] = array(
            'title' => 'DESIGNER',
            'priority' => 50,
            'callback' => 'dl_custom_designer_tab'
        );
    }
    return $tabs;
}

// The custom product tab content
function dl_custom_designer_tab() {
    global $post, $product;

    $group_name = 'designer';

    $designer = get_field( $group_name );

    echo '<p>'.$designer['designer_image'].'</p>';
    echo '<p>'.$designer['designer_name'].'</p>';
    echo '<p>'.$designer['designer_short_description'].'</p>';

    $designer_achievements = repeater_subfield( $group_name, 'designer_achievements', 'achievement' );

    // check if the repeater field has rows of data
    if( count($designer_achievements) > 0 ):
        echo '<ul>';
        
        // loop through the rows of data
        foreach( $designer_achievements as $achievement ){
            // display a sub field value
            echo '<li>'.$achievement.'</li>';
        }

        echo '<ul>';
    else:

        // "no rows found" optional message
        echo '<p><em>No data…</em></p>';

    endif;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works…

---

**Original answer:**

With [Advanced Custom Field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) Pro plugin to get the *Repeater* sub fields data, you will need to use [the documented way](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/), functions and methods [have_rows()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/have_rows/) and [get_sub_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_sub_field/), this way:

```
function dl_custom_designer_tab() {
    global $post;
    
    $designer = get_field('designer');
    
    echo '<p>'.$designer['designer_image'].'</p>';
    echo '<p>'.$designer['designer_name'].'</p>';
    echo '<p>'.$designer['designer_short_description'].'</p>';
    
    // check if the repeater field has rows of data
    if( have_rows('designer_achievements') ):
        echo '<ul>';
        // loop through the rows of data
        while ( have_rows('designer_achievements') ) : the_row();
            // display a sub field value
            echo '<li>' . get_sub_field('achievement') . '</li>';
        endwhile;
        
        echo '<ul>';
    else:

        // "no rows found" optional message
        echo '<p><em>No row founds in repeater…</em></p>';

    endif;
}
```

Comment: Already tried that one. And still not working. It just shows the else echo instead of the rows with content. Anyways thanks for the help and here is the screenshot on how I created the fields. https://ibb.co/mGzvv6

Comment: @JohnAshleyNohay I found a working way… I have reproduced your issue myself too, and I think that is a bug in the plugin related to product post type and repeater feature in ACF Pro. I have updated my answer with a working alternative… Try it and let me know. Thanks